# Get all products which have both product category

Tags: wp-query, query, woocommerce-offtopic

I need all products which have both categories. I am using a query below:

```
$args = array(
                        'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'),

                        'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms'    => array( 'shop', 'cat1' ),
                                'operator' => 'AND',
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

It's working correctly if cat1 category does not have any subcategory like cat1-1,cat1-2 etc. But when i made subcategory in backend of cat1 than result will give zero.

Query is same just no result if cat1 have subcategory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set `include_children` to false in the tax_query.

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => array( 'product', 'product_variation' ),

'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'product_cat',
        'field'            => 'slug',
        'terms'            => array( 'shop', 'cat1' ),
        'include_children' => false,
        'operator'         => 'AND',
    )
)
```

);

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters